# What does ps –ax | grep $$ > catch do?

Tags: linux, grep, ps

What does `ps –ax | grep $$ > catch` do? I would like to know what does this line executes. when I run the code it doesn't add anything to the output.

Comment: Did you look in the `catch` file that you just created?

Comment: Please don't add tags to the title. "linux ps=" makes no sense in the title.

Answer (score 2):

The command `ps -ax`
displays yours as well as other users' processes.

`grep` matches lines which match a regular expression. In this case, the regular expression is  `$$`, which the shell will expand to the process ID of the current shell.

Right angle bracket (`>`) redirects the output to a file called `catch`. If the file exists, it will first be truncated (emptied), otherwise it will be created.

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't just match your PID, but it will match any line from `ps -ax` that contains the sequence of characters represented by your PID. So if your PID is `23` you might also catch `1234`

Comment: And that old gotcha -- it will match your grep because that number is in its args.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way of doing things. You're asking ps to show:

- All your processes (default)
- plus - all other processes which have a tty (a option)
- plus - all other process that don't have a tty too (x option)
- then - filter down using `grep` to a single process, which you had in step 1

Something as simple as `ps -h $$ > catch` will probably do it. `ps` takes the PIDs of the processes you are interested in as command line options so if you know what you want, specify it directly, rather than hope the grep will work. The `-h` option is to remove the header line.

However, you have to be really careful of $$ in scripts because it means "this shell" but the concept of *this* depends on when and where it is called.

Consider the two commands:

```
$ sh -c "ps -ax | grep $$"
   3802 pts/0    Ss     0:11 bash
3658110 pts/0    S+     0:00 sh -c ps -ax | grep 3802
3658112 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep 3802
$ sh -c 'ps -ax | grep $$'
3658142 pts/0    S+     0:00 sh -c ps -ax | grep $$
3658144 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep 3658142
```

Scripts do this sort of thing all the time, see how the first has 3 lines but the second has only 2? This is because the first we are resolving `$$` then running the script and finding out "main" shell, but the second we are doing it the other way which of course has a different PID of the child shell and doesn't match the 3802 of the parent.

Which one is correct? It depends on what you are trying to do. If I'm looking for the main shell, I would generally set it to a variable first so its clear that's the one I want.